# Verify that 4 products are shown with € symbol

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, elements

I want to verify from this website: https://demo.nopcommerce.com/. There are 4 products shown with the Euro symbol by using for loop.

Code:

```
    List <WebElement> productcurrency = driver.findelEments(By.xpath(“span[text()=\”€\”]”));

system.out.println(“4”+ productcurrency.size());
```

Comment: Post your current code. What error are you getting / issue facing?

Comment: List <WebElement> productcurrency =driver.findelEments(By.xpath(“span[text()=\”€\”]”)); system.out.println(“4”+ productcurrency.size());

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any products in your application with euro(€) symbol. However I see there are 4 products with dollar($) symbol. Assuming this is what you want, try the below code:

```
List<WebElement> productcurrency  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'$')]"));
System.out.println("productcurrency  size is: " + productcurrency .size());
```

**Console output:**

```
productcurrency  size is: 4
```

**XPath expression explanation:**

`//span[contains(text(),'$')]` - This relative xpath expression will search the entire DOM for tag `span` which contains text `$`